# Place windows from remote machine on my local machine desktop?

Tags: windows, remote, remote-desktop

I am presently viewing the desktop of a remote machine running Rasbian (raspberry pi) on my local machine running Linux Mint using RealVNC. Teamviewer also works. But I don't want to see that remote machine's entire desktop, I just want to view/forward two or three of the remote machine's open windows on my local machine's desktop, as if they were windows created by local gui processes.

IOW, remote machine has a desktop, and on that desktop are several windows running processes. My local machine also has a desktop and there are a few open windows on it, too. I want to be able to add some of the remote machine's windows to my local desktop, not the entire remote desktop. And be able to re-arrange them on my desktop just as if they were windows running on my local machine, and (he asks too much!) be able to interact with the remoted windows just like I can with the local windows. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to do, this may also be either a job for `ssh -X` or plain old X, if you want to start new applications on the remote machine and have them show up locally for the duration.

Comment: Another way is to install X2Go-Server on your Raspbian (see http://dodger-tools.sourceforge.net/cms/index.php?id=100000604) and X2Go-client on your local machine. This enables you to run not even the desktop, but also "published Applications" (for more info, see http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php)